# Converting primitive array of int into ArrayList in Java: "java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion, converters

I'm wondering how I can convert a primitive array of integers to a list of Integer?

There's no compile error for:

```
    int[] nums = {0, 1};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums));
    list.get(0);
```

But this one:

```
    int[] nums = {0, 1};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums));
    int a = list.get(0);
```

fails with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [I cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer ([I and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Comment: int is not the same as Integer

Comment: Note that `new ArrayList(` is almost automatically a bug; that's a "[raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)", and tells the compiler to ignore its knowledge of the type system. You should instead write `new ArrayList<>(`. That way you'll get an appropriate error at compile-time, letting you know that your types don't match, instead of a `ClassCastException` at run-time.

Comment: Also -- you write that "There's no compile error for" your first example, but in fact *neither one* produces a compile error.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh! Good points :) I 99% agree with you. I can be wrong, but I think when the type is already defined in `List <Integer>`, adding `<Integer>` in `ArrayList<Ingeger>(` is not necessary and `ArrayList(` is fine (or maybe even better). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @NavidVafaei: As you can see from the OP's example, something like `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("string"))` is allowed by the compiler, even though it will raise an exception at run-time. And note that I'm **not** suggesting to add `<Integer>`; I'm **only** suggesting to add `<>` , as in `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("string"))`. The `<>` asks the compiler to deduce the type, so it's not a raw type, and the issue is detected at compile-time instead of at runtime.

Comment: The left side of `= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(nums))` is not primitive, so I agree with adding `<>` in that scenario :)

Comment: If you enable all compiler warnings, the compiler will tell you that using a raw type is a bad idea, for reasons which you have discovered for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1:

In Java 8:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums)
                      .boxed()
                      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

In Java 16 and later:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().toList();
```

**Note:** You might need to:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

### Solution 2:

Use for loop:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
for(int n : nums) {
    list.add(n);
}
```

### Solution 3:

Declare the original array as `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`:

```
Integer[] nums = {0, 1};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code `Arrays.asList(nums)` won't translate to an `ArrayList` with 2 values, viz. 1 and 2. It just has one value, `int[] { 1, 2 }`. In order to create the right `ArrayList`, you should use

`List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet you were trying to assign the type `int` to `Integer` type.

Autoboxing only happens for a single element (for example for one element of int to Integer).

So the `Arrays.asList()` cannot be used to convert all the elements from `int` to `Integer`.

Reference [link][1]

[1]: [https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitive-array-to-list#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20this%20won%E2%80%99t,to%20Integer%5B%5D](https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitive-array-to-list#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20this%20won%E2%80%99t,to%20Integer%5B%5D)).